# Pip installation in Colab with URL and requirements

Tags: pip, google-colaboratory

I would like to install the following package in COLAB with its requirements.
I would like to run this:

```
!pip install scratchai-nightly -r requirements.txt
```

The requirements are stored in a file `requirements.txt` located here:

```
https://github.com/iArunava/scratchai/blob/master/requirements.txt
```

I tried:

```
!pip install scratchai-nightly -r https://github.com/iArunava/scratchai/blob/master/requirements.txt
```

Afterwards, I tried:

```
https://github.com/iArunava/scratchai/blob/9472f64fd3a06a1daa51486b68f5d3d3c36ac2f0/requirements.txt
```

In both cases I get the following errors:

```
ERROR: Invalid requirement: '<!DOCTYPE html>' (from line 7 of https://github.com/iArunava/scratchai/blob/master/requirements.txt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!pip install scratchai-nightly -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iArunava/scratchai/master/requirements.txt`

Try this, because this page only contains requirements and it doesn't have any HTML data, and `https://github.com/iArunava/scratchai/blob/master/requirements.txt` this you tried to install, has HTML data so, `pip install` tried to download HTML stuff like `<!DOCTYPE html>` which doesn't exist in pip.

next time you are trying to get something from GitHub, click the raw button.
https://prnt.sc/1uzm8ht